# How a Slider control in WPF can snap on specific values?

Tags: wpf, slider

I want to create a slider, with values from 0 to 100 that I can slide like any other slider... but at position 30, 42 and 55 (for example) I want to snap to these values, to make easy to the user to stop the slider at them

edit: my solution was to have 2 slider, the first one is invisible, value 0 to 200, and the other one is the visible on, value 0 to 100
The visible one cannot be slide, only the the invisible. Like this i can make a gap, ex: when I'm between 50 and 75 on the invisible slider, it's equals to 50 on the visible one...

Comment: I don't but i think u can do this by manually setting value when ValueChanged event occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override OnValueChanged. See this article [DiscreteSlider - Adding Functionality with a Simple Control Subclass](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/06/12/discreteslider-a-simple-control-subclass.aspx) and then this artice [Silverlight slider control that snaps](http://blogs.microsoft.nl/blogs/ux/archive/2011/07/05/silverlight-slider-control-that-snaps.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Instead of using SmallChange, you would check where between your values the slider sits and snap to the nearest.