# Slider: How to snap to one tick, but not others

Tags: wpf

I'm making a media player speed selector, which goes from 0.5 to 2. This is how I have defined the Slider.

```
<Slider Maximum="2" Minimum="0.5" Ticks="0.5 0.75 1 2"/>
```

This is because 0.5, 0.75, 1 and 2 is the speeds that is the most desired play-speeds. So I could, if that was the only requirement, say IsSnapToTicksEnabled="True", but the user should also be allowed to select an value between these ticks, and at the same time still be able to snap to the specified ticks.

So, the thumb should snap to these ticks once the slider is close, but not when further away than ~0.1.  Is this possible?
We also have the RadControls from Telerik, if there is something specifically implemented there.

What I've tried so far is to listen to ValueChanged and check if the new value is between 1.1 and 0.9, and set it to 1 if it is. But that disables dragging completely.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106326/how-a-slider-control-in-wpf-can-snap-on-specific-values

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar.

I created 2 sliders:

One of them is invisible (from 0 to 100 for example), it's just a rectangle (invisible color) on top on the other slider, this is the one you will slide with your mouse.

The second slider is your graphic, from 0.5 to 2, like you actually have.

Now you just have to code your invisible slider, for example:

If InvisibleSlider < 10, then RealSlider stay at 0.5
If InvisibleSlider is between 10 and 30, then the value of RealSlider is InvisibleSlider * X ?

With that you can simulate that you stick where you have decided, eg: stick at 0.75 if the invisible slider is between 40 and 60, your mouse will move but the the graphic...

I don't know if I'm clear, and english is not my main language sorry